# how to retrive as a groups in mysql?

Tags: mysql

i have mysql table like below (mysql_version 8)

```
id  type    name
1   1       a
2   1       b
3   1       c
4   2       d
5   2       e
6   2       f
7   3       g
8   3       h
9   3       i
```

i am only able to manage to get all types using 3 query like

```
type1 = select * from table where type 1 limit 2;
type2 = select * from table where type 2 limit 2;
type3 = select * from table where type 3 limit 2;
```

i want to retrieve first two data rows of every type in single query
with grouping like a, b in type 1 and c , d in type 2 and g, h in type 3.

```
something like this collection below
[
'type1'=>['a','b'],
'type2'=>['d','e'],
'type3'=>['g','h']
]
```

thanks!!

Comment: Specify MySQL version - this is critical for your task. *i am only able to manage to get all types using 3 query like* 1) You cannot assign 2 values to single variable 2) LIMIT without ORDER BY makes no sense - this is a lottery. *i want to retrieve first two data rows* The term "first" not exists until you have defined the rows ordering which is unique.

Comment: i have edited my post. i m currently using mysql version 8.0.19

Comment: If so then 1st code in @ysth's answer is a solution. But I recommend to convert the subquery to CTE additionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first 2 for each type, first you need to define what you mean by first.  Lowest id?  Lowest name?  I'm going to assume name.

Using mysql 8+ or mariadb 10.2+, you use the row_number() function in a subselect (or CTE, if you prefer) for this:

```
select type, name
from (
    select
        type,
        name,
        row_number() over (partition by type order by name) as row_number
    from foo
) alias
where row_number < 3;

+------+------+
| type | name |
+------+------+
|    1 | a    |
|    1 | b    |
|    2 | d    |
|    2 | e    |
|    3 | g    |
|    3 | h    |
+------+------+
```

Or using a common table expression (CTE):

```
with ranked_foo as (
    select
        type,
        name,
        row_number() over (partition by type order by name) as row_number
    from foo
)
select type, name
from ranked_foo
where row_number < 3;
```

In earlier versions, you can emulate that using variables:

```
select type, name
from (
    select
        @rank:=if(@type=type,@rank+1,1) row_number,
        @type:=type type,
        name
    from (select @type:=null, @rank:=0) alias1
    cross join foo
    order by name
) ranked_foo
where row_number < 3;
```

If you want just one row for each type with both names, just wrap the previous query (as appropriate for your version) in a subselect:

```
select type, min(name) name1, max(name) name2
from (
    select type, name
    from (
        select
            type,
            name,
            row_number() over (partition by type order by name) as row_number
        from foo
    ) ranked_foo
    where row_number < 3
) ranked_foo_top_2
group by type;
```

Comment: @Akina I find subqueries more readable and only use CTEs if recursive or referenced more than once

Comment: added a CTE example